# remove first 2 rows in a dataframe based on the value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with stock tickers in a column and the next column is called 'Fast Add' which will either be populated with the value 'Add' or be empty.

I want to remove the 2 stocks tickers but only where the fast add column = ADD. the below code will remove the first 2 lines but i need to add a argument which only removes the first 2 lines where the 'Fast Add' column = 'Add'. Can someone help please

```
new_df = df_obj[2:]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) function in Pandas to remove specific indices from a DataFrame. Here's a code example for your use case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Ticker': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'Fast Add': ['Add', np.nan, 'Add', 'Add']
})

new_df = df.drop(df[df['Fast Add'] == 'Add'][:2].index)
```

`new_df` is a DataFrame with the following contents:

```
  Ticker Fast Add
1      B      NaN
3      D      Add
```

The approach here is to select all the rows you want to remove and then pass their indices into `DataFrame.drop()` to remove them.

References:

- https://showmecode.info/pandas/DataFrame/remove-rows/ (personal site)
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

IIUC something like this should work:

```py
df_obj["record_idx"] = df_obj.groupby('FastAdd').cumcount()
new_df = df_obj.query("record_idx >= 2 & FastAdd == 'ADD'")
```

You can also use a cheap hack like below:

```py
df_obj.sort_values("FastAdd", inplace = True)
new_df = df_obj.iloc[2:].copy()
```